# ndroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: title: , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

Hy everbody.

I need help in my query. I receive a warning but I don't know what is wrong.

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: title: , while compiling: SELECT       _id, display_name FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (account_name='ricardofilipe19@gmail.com' AND title!=GrupoSocios AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership' AND display_name like '%rui%') ORDER BY DISPLAY_NAME

here is my code

```
return getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
     new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,   ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + "='" + accountName + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + "!=" + nomeGrupo + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,
 null,
 "DISPLAY_NAME");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is data type of nomeGrupo ?

Comment: It's a string.   private String nomeGrupo = "My Group". That's indicate the name of the group that I need

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space in here and adding some quotes (`):

```
ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " !='" + nomeGrupo + "' AND "
```

Comment: Yes I get. My guess is that with  ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, I can't acess ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE information. I'm right?

Comment: That would seem reasonable.  I've updated my answer, try CONTENT_GROUP_URI.

Comment: Doesn'e work. Do you think that cursorJoiner can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote 'nomeGrupo' if you are including it in the SQL string.

i.e `'" + nomeGrupo + "'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I try this way and don't work. Appears the same error.

Comment: ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + "='" + accountName + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " !='" + nomeGrupo + "' AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,

Comment: My guess is that with ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, I can't acess ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE information. I'm right?

If yes, how I can countour this problem?